# Is there a microdata tag to designate whether a value is a number, string, or bool?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

There is an HTML5 attribute called `datetime` that indicates that a value type is a datetime. But I see no way to indicate whether a `itemprop` value in `span` tag is a string, bool, or number. Am I right that there is no way to include this kind of information in microdata? If so, is there some reason why this capability should be omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microdata specification only [differs between these types of values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values), which get derived from the HTML5 markup:

- **item** (if an element has an `itemprop` *and* an `itemscope` attribute)
- **absolute URL** (if the `itemprop` is specified on an URL property element like `a`, `video` etc.)
- **datetime** (if the `itemprop` is specified on a `time` element)
- **string**, i.e.,

  - for `meta` elements: the value of the `content` attribute
  - for `data` elements: the value of the `value` attribute
  - for `meter` elements: the value of the `value` attribute
  - for every other element: its *textContent*

While RDFa allows to specify the datatype with its [`datatype` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-rdfa-core-20130822/#A-datatype) …

```html
<span property="alive" datatype="xsd:boolean">true</span>
<!-- the value is boolean -->
```

… Microdata doesn’t offer such an attribute:

```html
<span itemprop="alive">true</span>
<!-- no way to denote that the value is boolean -->
```

There was the idea to [specify the datatype of Microdata properties in the vocabulary registry](http://www.w3.org/2011/htmldata/track/issues/3), but it [seems](https://github.com/w3c/microdata-rdf/issues/3#issuecomment-62029308) that there was no consensus for this.

#### What do to?

Vocabularies could define in their descriptions which values their properties should/must have.

The vocabulary Schema.org **expects** (and does intentionally not *require*) specific types. Examples:

- [`free` property](http://schema.org/free):

  > Values expected to be one of these types:
  >   [`Boolean`](http://schema.org/Boolean)

The vocabulary [vCard (as defined by the WHATWG)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#vcard) **requires** values types. Examples:

- [`anniversary` property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#md-vcard-anniversary):

  > The value must be a valid date string.
- [`sex` property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#md-vcard-sex):

  > The value must be one of `F`, meaning "female", `M`, meaning "male", `N`, meaning "none or not applicable", `O`, meaning "other", or `U`, meaning "unknown".

Of course one could use/create a Microdata vocabulary to make such statements about other Microdata vocabularies, similar to RDFS. Schema.org is [using RDFa to define their types/properties](http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html), and they also use RDFS, but instead of defining a range with [`rdfs:range`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_range) (which would mean that all property values are (also) of that type), they made their own property [`rangeIncludes`](http://schema.org/rangeIncludes), which doesn’t allow this inference:

> ```html
> <div typeof="rdf:Property" resource="http://schema.org/free">
>   <span class="h" property="rdfs:label">free</span>
>   <span property="rdfs:comment">A flag to signal that the publication is accessible for free.</span>
>   <span>Domain: <a property="http://schema.org/domainIncludes" href="http://schema.org/PublicationEvent">PublicationEvent</a></span>
>   <span>Range: <a property="http://schema.org/rangeIncludes" href="http://schema.org/Boolean">Boolean</a></span>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: It looks like the `meter` element can be used for numeric elements. "For numeric data, the meter element and its value attribute can be used instead." http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/

Comment: @dan: This is only about HTML5 semantics (and it’s bad advice, as [`meter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-meter-element) must not be used for *any* "numeric data"), and has no effect on the datatype of the Microdata value. It’s still a string as far as Microdata is concerned. When converting Microdata to RDF, tools [could, in some cases](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-microdata-rdf-20141216/#value-typing), determine that the property value of `meter` (as well as `data`) is double or integer -- but this is only relevant for the RDF, not the Microdata.