# Markup for linked Schema.org articleSection(s)

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to mark up article sections ([`articleSection`](http://schema.org/articleSection)) on my blog listing page. Each article section also has a link to go to that section.

Which of these syntaxes, if any, is correct as they produce different results in the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/):

```html
<a href="#"><span itemprop='articleSection'>section name 1</span></a>
```

Testing Tool result: `articleSection: section name 1`

```html
<span itemprop='articleSection'><a href="#">section name 2</a></span>
```

Testing Tool result: `articleSection: section name 2`

```html
<a href="#" itemprop='articleSection'>section name 3</a>
```

Testing Tool result: `articleSection: http://www.example.com/pagelocation/#`

Perhaps this matters, perhaps it doesn't.

Does having a link inside the `articleSection` property help? `articleSection` looks for 'text' not URL.

GoldStarBonus: Is there any way/advantage to associate a link to the articleSection name? If not, that's fine for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`articleSection` property](https://schema.org/articleSection) expects *Text* as value.

[In Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669), you can give a text value by *not* using an element that would specify an URL (like `a`, `area`, `link`, `video` etc.) or a datetime (`time`).

So don’t use `a`. `span` is fine, unless there is a more appropriate element defined in HTML5.

As far as Microdata and Schema.org are concerned, there is no difference between these:

- `<a href="#"><span itemprop="articleSection">…</span></a>`
- `<span itemprop="articleSection"><a href="#">…</a></span>`

As Schema.org does not define a type for an article section (e.g., `ArticleSection`), you can’t specify any additional data about such a section.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel much clearer on this now.