# How do you use link text as value in schema.org value?

Tags: html, metadata, schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to markup some HTML with [schema.org](http://schema.org) microdata, however I'm getting an issue with my markup:

Here's my current HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        <a href="example.com/1234">The name is here</a>
        <small>(Some extra info)</small>
    </h1>
    Tons more content about the thing
</div>
```

What I want to do is describe the existence of the thing and its name and tried:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <h1>
        <a href="example.com/1234" itemprop="name">The name is here</a>
        <small>(Some extra info)</small>
    </h1>
    Tons more content about the thing
</div>
```

But that gives me this incorrect metadata:

[image]

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <h1 itemprop="name">
        <a href="example.com/1234">The name is here</a>
        <small>(Some extra info)</small>
    </h1>
    Tons more content about the thing
</div>
```

But this is also incorrect as it incorrectly identifies `(Some extra info)` as part of the name (which it isn't):

[image]

**In conclusion, is there a way to apply `itemprop` to an `<a href=>` link *without* it using the URL as the value for the property?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microdata does not provide a way to denote that an `itemprop` on an `a` element should not produce a URL as value.

You have to add another element that

- is one of the elements that produces string values in Microdata ([tl;dr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669): not `time` and not one of the elements that can have a `href`/`src` attribute), and
- only contains the content that you want to have as value of the property.

In your example, you could add a `span` element:

```html
<a href="example.com/1234"><span itemprop="name">The name is here</span></a>
```

```html
<span itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/1234">The name is here</a></span>
```

Comment: Dang, is there a way that doesn't include introducing redundant elements, or can you give a link that supports this? I thought this was the case, but would like to read about it in the docs so I'm not bitten again.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669) I linked to shows which HTML5 elements produce which value. This is based on the Microdata section [Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values), which specifies an algorithm to decide what the value of a property must be. Your example would be the fourth case: "If the element is an `a` […] element […] The value is the absolute URL".

Comment: Double dang it. But, thanks for your answer :) Now I know.