# Structured markup data of website name

Tags: html, schema.org, google-search-console, microdata, google-rich-snippets

According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/site-name), you should add a markup data in order to include your site name in the search results:

> [image: Search results website name]

In their example of Microdata usage, they attach the website name to the page `title`:

```html
   <head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
   <title itemprop='name'>Your WebSite Name</title>
   <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" itemprop="url">
```

But obviously page titles are not the same as website name!
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microdata can be used [on any HTML5 element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669) (while [some elements come with special rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669)), so you don’t *have* to use the `title` element.

If you want to keep the markup in the `head`, or if you don’t have the site name as visible content on your homepage, you could use the `meta` element:

```html
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <title>Welcome to Foobar!</title>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Foobar" />
  <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/" />
</head>
```

But if you have the site name as visible content, for example in the page header, you could make use of it:

```html
<header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <h1 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/">Foobar</a></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why did Google use the title tag in their example? I can't see any case where this will make sense

Comment: @RonenTeva: Many websites use only the site name in the homepage’s `title`, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/ (title: "Stack Overflow") or https://www.google.com/ (title: "Google"). A common structure is `[site-name]` for the homepage, and `[page-name] [delimiter] [site-name]` for every other page.

Comment: Ohhh am I expected to only set it in the homepage and not on every page?

Comment: @RonenTeva: You may use `WebSite` on every page (after all, the site name is not the only thing this type is useful for, and Google is not the only consumer of it), but Google will only look on the site’s homepage for the [Site Name](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/site-name) markup: "Publish markup on your official website homepage"

Comment: So that's what I was missing :) Thanks.