# Microdata itemprop on parent div with children

Tags: html, semantic-markup, microdata

I am adding Microdata on a site, and wondering on which level the `itemprop` property should appear.

For example, I have the following markup:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <div class="author">
        <a href="http://www.author.com">Author's Name</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where should `itemprop` go, in the `a` element directly or it is possible to add it to `<div class="author">` and it would be parsed correctly?

Can I have the following:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <div class="author" itemprop="author">
        <a href="http://www.author.com">Author's Name</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <div class="author">
        <a href="http://www.author.com" itemprop="author">Author's Name</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words, does the `itemprop` property have to be defined on the element *directly* (such as an `a` or `img` tag) or it's possible to define it on a wrapper `div` with the content actually being in a child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the property (what value it should have).

An `itemprop` on an element with `href` or `src` attribute (e.g., `a` or `img`) creates a URI value: it takes the value of the `href`/`src` attribute, not the element’s content.

- Here the `author` property has the string value "`Author's Name`":

  ```html
  <div itemprop="author">
      <a href="http://example.com/">Author's Name</a>
  </div>
  ```
- Here the `author` property has the URI value "`http://example.com/`":

  ```html
  <div>
      <a href="http://example.com/" itemprop="author">Author's Name</a>
  </div>
  ```

There are some more exceptions, like the `meter` element or the `time` element. You can refer to a summary in [my answer about datatypes in Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669).

Leaving these exceptions aside, if the value should be a string, and you have, let’s say, only `div` elements, it doesn’t matter on which element you specify the `itemprop`, so these three snippets all have the string "`bar`" as value for the `foo` property:

```html
<div itemprop="foo">
  bar
</div>
```

```html
<div itemprop="foo">
  <div>
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div itemprop="foo">
  <div>
    <div>
      bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! What if it the contents of a `div` with `itemprop` is an `img`? Would a [ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject) be created then?

Comment: @p4sh4: Do you mean `<div itemprop="foo"><img src="photo.jpg"></div>`? No, because `div` is an element that creates a string value: it looks for its element content (and the element content of all children). Because `img` is empty (i.e., it has no element content), the property `foo` would have no content. ··· Also note that Microdata never automatically creates items from a vocabulary (like Schema.org). Microdata is just a syntax that can be used with many different vocabularies (it just cares about strings, URIs and datetimes). You’d have to use `itemtype` for getting an `ImageObject`.

Comment: Yes. In fact, I was asking about Schema.org, someone edited my post to be about Microdata, that's strange... So, do you mean that in case of Schema.org, it would automatically create an ImageObject item "from a vocabulary" (not sure what that means), as opposed to Microdata?

Comment: @p4sh4: The edit was mine ;) and I think it was correct (I rolled your edit back): You seem to ask how Microdata works. Schema.org is a vocabulary (with types like `Person` and properties like `name`), Microdata is a syntax (with HTML5 attributes like `itemprop`, `itemtype` etc.). You can use the vocabulary Schema.org, for example, with the syntaxes JSON-LD or RDFa instead of Microdata. So these (vocabulary vs. syntax) are two different things.

Comment: Ah, got it! It was a bit confusing... Thanks!