# Can I use the meta element for all Schema.org properties in Microdata?

Tags: html, meta, schema.org, microdata

I just wanna ask if I can use meta tags to all properties in Schema.org or use it whenever I want?

Example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">

       <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="2" /> 
       <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="144" />
   </div>
   <meta itemprop="name" content="name here">
   <meta itemprop="description" content="description" />
</div>
```

Because I don't know if I'm already abusing the use of meta tags and also I don't wanna make those things visible to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use the `meta` element for *all* properties, but for many.

In Microdata, [property values can have 4 different types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669):

- string
- datetime
- URL
- item

The `meta` element can only be used if the value should be a *string*.

For a *datetime* value, Microdata defines that the `time` element should be used (but in practice, using `meta` should work here, too).

HTML5 defines another element that is by default hidden: `link`. This [must be used instead of `meta` if the value is a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669). So in Microdata you’d use `link` if the value should be a *URL*.

For an *item* value, neither `meta` nor `link` can be used, so you have to use a different element (like `div`).

#### Schema.org

In Schema.org, each property has an expected value. Some also have multiple expected values. And note that this is just a recommendation, you don’t have to follow it.

Example:

- For [`name`](http://schema.org/name), it’s *Text*. So you could use a `meta` element.
- For [`url`](http://schema.org/url), it’s *URL*. So you could use a `link` element.
- For [`parent`](http://schema.org/parent), it’s another *item* (`Person`). So you could use a `div`/`span` (or a more appropriate) element.