# Is a wrapping span element necessary for a Schema.org telephone link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, schema.org, microdata, phone-number

The examples I often see for using Schema.org Microdata use a lot of extra `span` elements, such as the following:

```html
<span itemprop="telephone">
  <a href="tel:+18506484200">
     850-648-4200
  </a>
</span>
```

Is the extra `span` element really necessary or is it acceptable to place the `itemprop` in the `a` tag? Like so:

```html
<a href="tel:+18506484200" itemprop="telephone">
     850-648-4200
</a>
```

The latter example seems so much cleaner, but the examples I see always seem to use separate `span` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `span` element would generate a `Text` value, the `a` element would generate a `URL` value ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669)).

Schema.org’s [`telephone`](http://schema.org/telephone) property expects a `Text` value:

> **Values expected to be one of these types**
>   `Text`

Note that you don’t *have* to follow this advice. It is possible to use values that are not expected. There is an issue that asks to expect `URL` values, too: [Make the telephone property more structured (not just Text)](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/188).

Comment: By saying that I don't *have* to, are you suggesting that Google will probably parse the shortened markup even if it's not strictly valid?

Comment: @dave: It’s the other way around. It is valid to use whatever value type you want, and every conforming Microdata parser will parse it correctly automatically. -- But each consumer (e.g., Google) decides which value types to support for which of their features (e.g., rich search results). Even if Schema.org would explicitly expect an `URL` value, a consumer could still decide to support only `Text` values (or vice versa). The consumer’s documentation will hopefully note if that’s the case, and if the documentation doesn’t, it hopefully means that they support Schema.org’s expected values.