# Using containedInPlace property within a table with links

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have a table of villages within a city. I plan on adding schema.org microdata on each of these villages to specify their relation to their parent city. As I am just learning about microdata, I am a confused about how the property [containedInPlace](http://schema.org/containedInPlace) works in relation to [Place](http://schema.org/Place), especially in a table will links. Will this syntax be semantically correct?:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Place'>
  <h1><span itemprop='name'>San Andres</span></h1>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Village name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Other info</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a itemprop='containedInPlace' href='/santa-ana.html'>Santa Ana</a>
        </td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Other info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a itemprop='containedInPlace' href='/santiago.html'>Santiago</a>
        </td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Other info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</article>
```

Since `itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Place'` was placed in the `<article>` tag which contains the table, do the villages containing `itemprop='containedInPlace'` relate now to the city `San Andres`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Microdata, it doesn’t matter on which HTML elements it gets specified ([as long as you use `itemprop` on elements with suitable datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669)). So there is nothing special about using `table` instead of e.g. `div` etc.

Your example conveys that the place "San Andres" is part of two places which are identified by the URIs `/santa-ana.html` and `/santiago.html`. If you want to convey that the two places are part of San Andres, you have to use the property [`containsPlace`](http://schema.org/containsPlace) instead of [`containedInPlace`](http://schema.org/containedInPlace).

And if you want to provide more data about these places on that page (e.g., their names), you have to provide items (with `itemscope`) instead of just URL values.

```html
<tr itemprop="containsPlace" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
  <td>
    <a itemprop="url" href="/santa-ana.html"><span itemprop="name">Santa Ana</span></a>
  </td>
  <td itemprop="description">Description</td>
  <td>Other info</td>
</tr>
```

(And always use the most specific type available. For example, for a city you should use [`City`](http://schema.org/City) instead of the parent type `Place`.)

Comment: Thank you. But in the code you have provided, since you declared another itemtype, will it override the previous city itemtype in <article itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Place'>? How will I be able to add another itemprop referring back to the city?

Comment: @JAT86: 1) Each `itemscope` creates a new item. There is no concept of overwriting anything. 2) If you say `Place[1] containsPlace Place[2]`, there is typically no need to also say `Place[2] containedInPlace Place[1]`, as the properties `containsPlace` and `containedInPlace` are defined to be inverse. You can still add this, if you want, e.g., with a `link` element: `<link itemprop="containedInPlace" href="/san-andres.html" />` (which would just be a URL value, again).