# Correct Microdata syntax for breadcrumbs NOT in a list?

Tags: html, schema.org, breadcrumbs, microdata

Trying to determine the correct syntax for using Microdata inside my breadcumbs implementation. Everything I have read seems to lean towards the fact that the breadcrumbs are structured inside an ordered or unorderd list. Mine is not.

```
<body itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"> 
...
  <div class="breadcrumbs" itemprop="breadcrumb">
     <a href="" property="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a> 
     <span class="delimiter"> &gt; </span>
     <a href="">Parent Item</a> 
     <span class="delimiter"> &gt; </span>
     <span>Child</span>
  </div>
...
</body>
```

If I run it inside [Google's tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) it seems correct, but compared to their example it is missing a lot of elements and doesn't have the structure of their example `BreadcrumbList`.

I'm also a little confused about the correct properties for the links. Should they all have `title` and `url` properties?

I was looking at the examples at the bottom of the page here: http://schema.org/WebPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`breadcrumb`](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) property expects one of two values:

- `Text`
- [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)

If you provide a `Text` value (like you do in the example), you can’t provide data about each link. If you are fine with that, the Microdata in your example is correct (but it also contains RDFa, which doesn’t seem to make sense, at least not without further context; so if you didn’t add them intentionally, you might want to remove the `property` attributes).

If you want to provide data about each link, you have to provide a `BreadcrumbList` value.

For the Microdata, it doesn’t matter whether or not you use a list. If the example uses `ol`→`li`→`a`→`span`, you could as well use something like `div`→`span`→`a`→`span`. You just have to make sure to use the [correct element type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669).

If you can’t add parent elements to the `a` elements, it’s still possible to use `BreadcrumbList`. But then you would have to duplicate the URL with a `link` element inside the `a` element.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I ended up adding the appropriate parents and property tags. Also removed the RDFa syntax that was there when I found the code so it is all one type of syntax.